# Trouble adding data in list in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm using listbox to display a list of items,the XAML code for it is given below,

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="List" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="612" Margin="6,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="443" SelectionChanged="List_SelectionChanged_1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400" Height="50">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbName" Width="400" Height="44" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

And i just populate the list by the following C# code,

```
foreach (var item in categoryDetails.Category)
        {
           CategoryDisplay data = new CategoryDisplay();
           data.Name = item.accountName;
           data.Id = item.accountID;
           this.List.Items.Add(data);
        }
```

Everything goes fine until the last step,when

```
this.List.Items.Add(data);
```

is executed, there comes an error stating that,

```
An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
```

What could be the problem? What should i do to rectify it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your collection at `this.List.Items` has not been initialised.

When you declare your collection (let's assume for a minute that it is an ObservableCollection, but I can't see from your code what the type should be) then you need to initialise it to `new ObservableCollection<AccountDetail>()` before you can add items to it.

Answer (score 0):

A System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.ItemCollection  (your Items) should be initialised to an empty collection by default according to the documentation. Have you set it to null somewhere in your code execution block? The property does not have a setter in wp7.

Either way, a better and more efficient approach to assigning a data source to a control is to create your collection in one go and then assign it to the controls ItemSource property

```
 var data = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

 this.List.ItemsSource = from i in data select new CategoryDisplay() { id = i, Name = i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) };
```

Comment: Thanks @FunksMaName it was right, but sorry i just wrongly entered the error. now i've edited my question with the right one, pls do have a look at it.

Comment: Is it possible that you are trying to update the list from a non-UI thread? Can't tell from the code above, but if this is the case, then wrap your foreach block within a dispatcher block such as  Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            { //Code here });